# Make synchronous post request from react to flask to get dict

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Context:
I'm building a app that can plot graph structures in electron with react. My backend is some Matlab code that can perform analysis on the graph struct. I'm using flask as the middle man communicating between them.

In the GUI i have a button that should be able to load the data that is provided in a excel file to the GUI. This should be done by a post request that uses a matlab script to load the data from the excel file and then returns this to javascript.

I have tried using something like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/getGriddata', {
method : 'POST',
headers : {
'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
},

          body : JSON.stringify(fileObj.path)
    
    
      }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setGriddata(data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The problem is that this code won't wait for the flask function to be finished. The flask function takes about 10 seconds depending on the graph size. Therefor i want to make this call in sync with my javascript code so that after the request, i can assure that the new griddata is defined.

Question:
Is there some way to ensure this when using fetch?
Do i need to find a different way of connecting to flask, if so what would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

Instead of using the fetch api, another post brought me to the XMLHttpRequest. This works synchronously if the parameter is set to false.

With this my code looks like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST",'http://localhost:5000/getGriddata',false);
request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
request.send(JSON.stringify(fileObj.path));
console.log(request.response)
console.log(request.responseText)
setGriddata(JSON.parse(request.responseText))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using callbacks, try using async/await

```
const fetchGridData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/getGriddata', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(fileObj.path)
        });

        const result = await response.json();

        setGriddata(result)
    } catch(error) {
        console.error("fetchGridData =>", error)
    }
}
```

Comment: This still does not wait for the data to load but returns a undefined object. Does this have to be called in a async context?

Comment: Yeah, you will need to await fetchGridData()